# What is the Python "Magic" method used in the "bafang-python" package?

Tags: python

I have been trying to get this piece of code working:

https://github.com/philippsandhaus/bafang-python

There is this `Magic()` method which only confuses me because Python has some magic methods also. I'm also a beginner in Python.

The problem is in this part:

```
connect_cmd = Struct('connect',
  Magic('\x11\x51\x04\xB0\x05')
)
```

It is a serial message but what is `Magic()` and how I can get it working?

Comment: This is part of why `import *` makes code hard to read -- it's not obvious what was imported from where.

Comment: It is probably defined in **construct** : `from construct import *`

Comment: On PyPI magic module is to interface with libmagic, maybe that is it?

Comment: It's part of an **old** version of `construct`; in the new version it's renamed `Const`. See https://github.com/construct/construct/blob/da7a6cb465ac9d4c38626f97ac20178ee9c20fa2/docs/transition28.rst

Comment: Python's magic methods are surrounded by double underscores, not named Magic(). That is an imported method.

Comment: Your problem illustrates one of the reasons the python `from xyz import *` type of import is not a good idea: you have to guess where a reference comes from. In this case it looks like the `construct` import provides Magic and Struct and others - and `construct` isn’t in the github. Go ask the author?

Comment: @barny, `construct` certainly is in github -- see the link in my answer (which I found from its entry in PyPi).

Comment: Not in the github linked by OP. Maybe the one you found is the ‘right’ one or not. Who knows.

Comment: @barny, ...given as the old one implements (well, used to implement) the API used by the OP's code, it seems pretty clear-cut. If someone says they're having a problem with `requests` or `numpy`, we don't bother looking at whether there's a separate library with the same name unless there's actually evidence to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`construct.Magic` is the old name for `construct.Const`. (This code was presumably written for a version of the `construct` library before 2.8).

See https://github.com/construct/construct/blob/master/docs/transition28.rst, describing a large series of renames:

> `Magic` was made `Const`

---

The reason for the name can be inferred from [the documentation](https://github.com/construct/construct/blob/b8c1b64c982eaf68f257cd9d56db617c0ed1a041/docs/misc.rst) (emphasis added):

> **Const** - 
>   A constant value that is required to exist in the data and match a given value. If the value is not matching, ConstError is raised. **Useful for so called magic numbers,** signatures, asserting correct protocol version, etc.

Comment: A side note, only because I had something very different in my head when I read the question title; ipython has [magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html). I've seen them called "magic methods" and the IDE I use is for Python but supports IPython magic commands in the console.

Comment: @roganjosh, ...I wouldn't call that a Python feature; it's very much an add-on IPython, Jupyter, &c. have separately amended as opposed to part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

"Magic" methods in python are the methods which provide operator overloading. The term "magic" does not appear in the python language with reference to these methods, and many users prefer not to use the term as it suggests incomprehensibility. See [this tutorial](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) for more information on these if needed.

The `Magic` function (or possibly class) cited in your link is not defined in the context of that repo, so it is not possible to say what it does with the information provided. Possibly more research into the committer's other repositories would turn up the `construct` module that he imports from.

EDIT: Apparently there is a library called `construct` which is well known to a subset of python users, but not explicitly referenced by the author you cite. Sigh. https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/construct

Comment: Wasn't well-known to me, btw -- I found it via its PyPi entry. Since PyPi is used by pip, it's the closest thing to a canonical index of Python modules. If `bafang-python` had had a `setup.py` that called out the dependency, though, there would have certainly been less guesswork.

Comment: So how do I install it (construct)?

Comment: It seems to be pip-installable, so `pip install construct` should get you there. However, in the long run global installs cause heartache and regret, so I suggest working in a virtual environment. (details are searchable, out of scope for this comment)

Comment: ...doubly so if you want to install an older version of `construct` that the code will work with unmodified -- using a virtualenv means you aren't exposing old code to every Python user on your machine (and thus conflicting with any software that needs an up-to-date version of the same library). `pip install 'construct<2.8'` should get you the most recent pre-2.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

I am the original author of the github repo. I updated the code to current [Construct](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) version 2.9, added a [requirements.txt](https://github.com/philippsandhaus/bafang-python/blob/master/requirements.txt) and also removed the `import *` stuff. So things should be more clear now and it should be working for you.

```
 connect_cmd = Struct('connect',
   Magic('\x11\x51\x04\xB0\x05')
 )
```

has now been [changed](https://github.com/philippsandhaus/bafang-python/blob/master/protocol.py) to

```
connect_cmd = Struct(
    'connect_cmd' / Const(b"\x11\x51\x04\xB0\x05")
)
```